# Is there a default order in which results will be returned in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

If I query "SELECT * FROM table" will the order of the output always be the same whenever I run this query? This has been my observation so far, but I was curious if there was any guarantee of this behavior.

Comment: Nope, no guarantee. It does seem to exhibit what seems like consistent behavior, but certain things can change that. So you shouldn't count on it.

Comment: Thanks, want to put that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case i think there is a guarantee.
Some queries in Hive won't generate MR jobs and instead will IO the table directly in a serial way.
In your case, querying `select * from table` will not generate a MR job (unless `table` is a view).
Reading the table with a single process, reads from the first file to the last and from the head of each file to the end. hence, I believe that the order of the output in this way will be the same whenever you'll run the query.

This is of course not right in the case of MR jobs generated from the SQL.